MSBuild Net 8 property for build as single file
I am using Azure DevOps Server (on Prem) and am trying to build a solution (windows service, C#) for Net 8.0.204.
I have it working, and it is producing the Artifact that I can use in the release.
The issue is that when I also using the publishing wizard in Visual Studio, In the publish profile, I have the option to set the deployment mode to 'self-contained', the target runtime and the 'produce single file'.   These create a bin directory with only a few files contained.
When I run the build in Azure DevOps, I am missing these settings and the bin folder contains a lot of content - I believe I need to add the settings as /P: parameters under MSBuild Arguments but can't find up-to-date examples.
Does anyone have some examples? The only ones I have are for web projects and this is a windows console project.
Regards
Update: my Solution
Here is the solution I ended up with - with help from Jonathan below (have marked his post as the answer).

I needed to create a new publishing profile using the
FolderPublish option - this created a publish folder off of the bin directory (I needed to make note of) and set the
self-contained and produce single file flags.

I also needed to make note of the Target Runtime (win-64). Inside of
the publish xml (.pubxml) file this is set as
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>

Using the plural.  I needed to add the same property to my project
(.csproj) but as plural.
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>

Without this, the restore step previous to the build failed to
download the correct runtime.

On the msbuild step, I needed to add the following two parameters in
the ms build arguments line.
 -t:publish -p:PublishProfile=MyProfile.pubxml

Both parameters are needed.

When the build completed, my Copy Files step, copied the files
from the publish directory (noted above) into the artifact staging
directory .



Are you looking for how to use the publish profile .pubxml file? e.g. dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile (or msbuild -t:publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile)

For the build step what task are you using? DotNetCoreCLI? MSBuild? VSBuild? Some other task?

I was hoping there were some msbuild properties that I could use that produced the output in the bin folder as a single executable with the .net framework included (as per publish).   I have added a 'dotnet core' publish step after my 'msbuild' step but the MS documentation I have found focuses on web apps and not console (service) apps.  I've created a TestProfile.pubxml which has the appropriate settings in it, but unsure if it needs to be called in the msbuild step as /p:Publishprofile or in the dotnetpublish step (note: I use msbuild not dotnet build at the moment)

The MSBuild task will invoke MSBuild. Use msbuildArguments to pass any valid MSBuild arguments, e.g msbuildArguments: '-t:publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile'

can you promote your first post as an answer and I can accept it?

Create or use a publish profile .pubxml file. In the publish profile file, the appropriate flags can be set.
The profile can be passed to MSBuild with the PublishProfile property. Note that the property expects the filename without the .pubxml extension.
Specifying the publish target and the PublishProfile property (for a file named 'FolderProfile.pubxml') will look like the following if using the dotnet CLI:
dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile

Or the following if using MSBuild:
msbuild -t:publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile

